# Addlistener for network status is not working in Ionic 7.1.1

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

ionic 7.1.1 - Capacitor 5.2.3
The problem I have is that it detects the network connection type and status the first time, but the listener doesn't update the variables due to its asynchrony. I have to, for example, touch the mobile's back button for the variables to update. I would appreciate it if you could help me resolve this. Thank you very much!

In app.component.ts, the following code:

```
async initializeApp() {
    await this.platform.ready();

    this.checkConnection();

    Network.addListener('networkStatusChange', async (status) => {
      this.global.control_red = status.connected;
      this.global.control_red_tipo = status.connectionType;
    });

    SplashScreen.hide();
}

async checkConnection() {
    try {
      const status = await Network.getStatus();
      this.global.control_network = status.connected;
      this.global.control_network_type = status.connectionType;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error ', error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a behavior subject to store and retrieve the variables.